# Java 14 and 17 32-bit download for Windows

Tags: java, windows

I am trying to find a site to download below Java versions but I cannot find any. All versions I have found are in 64-bit.

- Java SE Development kit 17.0.1 32-bit
- Java SE Development Kit 14 32-bit

Who knows any site I can download them?

Comment: IIRC there is no Oracle-supported 32-bit after Java 10.

Comment: @bjorke07 of out curiosity, what is the reason they do not provide 32-bit after java 10? Do you know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out this site, it usually has all the Java versions packed and ready to go: https://adoptium.net/releases.html

Or this: http://www.oldversion.com.de/windows/java-platform/